# Aborting AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have AJAX request that takes data from remote file and displays in a div on a page. The AJAX is called and div with data is displayed when user hovers mouse over a link, and it disappears when the mouse is moved out of the link. The div displays immediately, but when mouse is moved out there is about 5 second delay between moving mouse out and hiding the div.

I presume it has something to do with AJAX request blocking the hide function, because when I removed AJAX request the div hides immediately.

Is there something I could do to abort, kill or ignore AJAX when the mouse is removed from the link and just hide the div no matter what?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
$(function(){

var showPopup = function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/process.cfm",
        data: "id=" + 1,
        success: function(data){
            $(".profilePopup").html(data);

            if ($(data).find(".profileResult").length) {
                var text = $(data).find(".profileResult").html();
                $(".profilePopup").html(text);
            }
        }
    });

    $(".profilePopup").show();
}

var hidePopup = function(){
    $(".profilePopup").hide();
}

$("#username").mouseover(showPopup);
$("#username").mouseout(hidePopup);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var xhr = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "some.php",
        data: "name=Somename",
        success: function(msg){
           alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        }
    });

    //kill the request
    xhr.abort()
```

Comment: I have assigned AJAX call to a variable and then killed it with abort() in the hidePopup() function just before hiding the popup. Unfortunately, this does not solved the problem, and the popup is still "stuck" for at least 5-6 seconds before disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

you can abort the ajax request, using the jxhr object :

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

something like this :

```
var jxhr_object = $.ajax({
    url: "some.php",    
    success: function(){
       do something
    }
});

//kill the request
jxhr_object.abort()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/process.cfm",
    async: true,
    data: "your data",

    success: function(msg){
       alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    }
});

//kill the request
xhr.abort()
```

This will not make your browser freeze.

**async: true,**