# How can I abort an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am planning on implementing a series of jQuery AJAX calls in my website and would like to develop a function to abort an AJAX call. How can I do this? I read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122921/aborting-ajax-request) already but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: its a regular request response. you cant stop it in the middle ( gracefully)

Comment: Show us your code. How are you using the code on that post?

Comment: Better dup; [Abort Ajax requests using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery)

Comment: you mean stop an ajax call depending on a response from another ajax call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to assign your ajax request to variable,

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
***
});
```

then call `abort()`

```
xhr.abort();
```

Answer (score 0):

In a single use of AJAX it is simple. The XMLHttpRequest has a abort method, which cancels the request.

```
// creating our request
xhr = $.ajax({
url: 'ajax/progress.ftl',
success: function(data) {
//do something
}
});

// aborting the request
xhr.abort();
```

The xhr object also contains a readystate which contains the state of the request(UNSENT - 0, OPENED - 1, HEADERS_RECEIVED - 2, LOADING - 3 and DONE - 4). So we can use this to check whether the previous request was completed.

```
// abort function with check readystate
function abortAjax(xhr) {
if(xhr && xhr.readystate != 4){
xhr.abort();
}
}

// this function usage
abortAjax(xhr);
```